# Error:Object #<ui> has no method 'containsLatLng'

Tags: javascript, google-maps, kml, polygon, geoxml3

Iam trying to find the polygon in which the given cordinate resides.

Here is the code for parsing the kml file :

```
for (var i = 0; i < doc[0].placemarks.length; i++) 
            {
                for(var j= 0; j<doc[0].placemarks[i].Polygon[0].outerBoundaryIs[0].coordinates.length; j++)
                {
                    var poly_lat = doc[0].placemarks[i].Polygon[0].outerBoundaryIs[0].coordinates[j].lat;
                    var poly_lon = doc[0].placemarks[i].Polygon[0].outerBoundaryIs[0].coordinates[j].lng;
                    arr_cord[j] = new google.maps.LatLng(poly_lat,poly_lon);
                    //arr_cord[i] = poly_lat + "," + poly_lon;

                //;
                }
                //alert(arr_cord);
                arr_polyoptions[i] = { path: arr_cord,strokeColor: "#FF0000",strokeOpacity: 0.8,strokeWeight: 2,fillColor: "#0000FF",fillOpacity: 0.6 };
                //polygons[i] = new google.maps.Polygon(cord_polyOptions);
                styles[i] = doc[0].placemarks[i].styleID;
                //alert(doc[0].placemarks.polygon.outerBoundaryis.LinearRing.coordinates);
            }
```

Now for checking through the polygons I use :

```
for(var curr = 0;curr<arr_polyoptions.length;curr++)
            {
                //var curr_polygon = polygons[curr];
                console.log(arr_polyoptions[curr]);
                var curr_polygon = new google.maps.Polygon(arr_polyoptions[curr]);
                //var isWithinPolygon = curr_polygon.containsLatLng(place.geometry.location);
                var isWithinPolygon = curr_polygon.containsLatLng(place.geometry.location);
                alert("isWithinPolygon = " + isWithinPolygon);
                if(isWithinPolygon == 'true')
                {
                    alert(styles[curr]);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

But the code produces the error Object # has no method 'containsLatLng' on the line var isWithinPolygon = curr_polygon.containsLatLng(place.geometry.location);

Is there anyone out there who can help me in this problem? Thank you in advance

On logging the curr_polygon object,the result in console is

```
ui
fillColor: "#0000FF"
fillOpacity: 0.6
gm_accessors_: Object
gm_bindings_: Object
latLngs: hg
b: Array[1]
0: hg
b: Array[2418]
[0 … 99]
0: N
jb: 41.8019457978553
kb: -87.62588976266039
```

if it helps

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the content in Chrome console ? You should be able to see `curr_polygon` keys

Comment: ui
fillColor: "#0000FF"
fillOpacity: 0.6
gm_accessors_: Object
gm_bindings_: Object
latLngs: hg
b: Array[1]
0: hg
b: Array[2418]
[0 … 99]
0: N
jb: 41.8019457978553
kb: -87.62588976266039

Answer (score 2):

The method name for a polygon is containsLocation, not containsLatLng.

[geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly)

```
 containsLocation(point:LatLng, polygon:Polygon) | boolean | Computes whether the given point lies inside the specified polygon.
```

You didn't post your code to include the API, but you do also need to load the geometry library.

[Example using geoxml3 and the geometry library](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/votemap_sidebar_geometryLibrary.html)

Comment: I changed the checking to var isWithinPolygon = containsLocation(place.geometry.location,curr_polygon);  But shows error containsLocation is not defined.BTW this is the gogole map decalration - <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&region=us&language=en&sensor=true"></script>

Comment: The full method is google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation() ([example](http://geocodezip.com/v3_simpleMap_containslocation.html)). If that doesn't solve the problem, please post more complete code or a jsfiddle that exhibits the problem.

Comment: That corrects the error.But Iam searching for the location in the city itself. But returns false for all the polygons in the kml file. If the parameters I have given for the function is not correct,will there be any error messages or simply return false?

Comment: For an answer to that you will need to provide more data: 1. a polygon; 2. a location that is in that polygon for which containsLocation returns false.

Comment: Can you please provide your email id or personal contact id or something so that I can directly chat with you? @geocodezip

Comment: No.  I don't do this via chat or email.

Answer (score 0):

In the Google maps v3 we have another method. You have to use containsLocation instead of containsLatLng. Here is the best example.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation